# DUAL table not returning data on Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

What can lead DUAL not to return the expected data on something so simple as a `SYSDATE` selection?

```
SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL;

SYSDATE ORA-01403 no data found
```

I believed that once connected with "some" permissions, those queries could not really fail.

Comment: What happens if you do `select * from dual`? Perhaps someone created a table named `dual` (if that's even possible :)).

Comment: You might try `SELECT SYSDATE FROM SYS.DUAL` to make sure that nobody has created a table named `DUAL` in your local schema. You might also try `SELECT * FROM DBA_OBJECTS WHERE OBJECT_NAME='DUAL'`. This last statement should return two rows - the TABLE named SYS.DUAL, and a synonym named PUBLIC.DUAL which references SYS.DUAL. Best of luck.

Comment: And looking at the error a bit more closely, it might be that someone has defined another object named `SYSDATE` - so try `SELECT * FROM DBA_OBJECTS WHERE OBJECT_NAME = 'SYSDATE'`. This should return 0 rows unless someone has been messing around. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

As Bob suggested "SELECT SYSDATE FROM SYS.DUAL" might work

Comment: A user-created table named `DUAL` would be a bug.  If such a thing exists, drop it.